# "Trois fois plus" ou "trois fois de plus"

Tags: prépositions, comparatifs

> Pierre gagne 2 000 euros par mois, tandis que Marie gagne trois fois ___.

Devrait-on remplir le blanc de "plus" ou de "de plus" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To express the idea of "three {X} times the amount of ...":

> Pierre gagne 2 000 euros par mois, tandis que Marie gagne **trois fois plus** (que lui).

"De plus" denotes "extra/another 500 {X} euros":

> Pierre gagne 2 000 euros par mois, tandis que Marie gagne **500 euros de plus** (que lui).

Similarly, in the case of "700 {X} euros less":

> Pierre gagne 2 000 euros par mois, tandis que Marie gagne **700 euros de moins** (que lui).

Answer (score 0):

Trois fois plus : you multiply : Mary gagne 3x2000=6000 euros.
Trois fois de plus : you count the occurences and find 3 more :
 son patron l'a invitée à diner 5 fois: trois fois de plus que lui (Pierre seulement 2 fois}